# Expecting initializer (unbound)

Tags: daemon

Hello so I am trying to build Monero and I am getting the following error with a dependency. I could fix it (I think) but it seems to be fairly esoteric and shouldn't be happening. Has anyone got this before?

```
external/unbound/util/log.h:75:27: error: expected initializer before 'ATTR_FORMAT'
   75 |  const char* format, ...) ATTR_FORMAT(printf, 2, 3);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
external/unbound/util/log.h:138:40: error: expected initializer before 'ATTR_FORMAT'
  138 | void log_info(const char* format, ...) ATTR_FORMAT(printf, 1, 2);
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
external/unbound/util/log.h:145:39: error: expected initializer before 'ATTR_FORMAT'
  145 | void log_err(const char* format, ...) ATTR_FORMAT(printf, 1, 2);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
external/unbound/util/log.h:152:40: error: expected initializer before 'ATTR_FORMAT'
  152 | void log_warn(const char* format, ...) ATTR_FORMAT(printf, 1, 2);
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
external/unbound/util/log.h:177:42: error: expected initializer before 'ATTR_FORMAT'
  177 | void fatal_exit(const char* format, ...) ATTR_FORMAT(printf, 1, 2);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also manually built unbound to see if it hit this error and it does not.

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: What compiler and platform ?

Comment: I think its this gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: Your best bet is to file a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero with that info.

Comment: Okay I can do that!